# why cant i get the json object out of the url

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, web-services

I have this [url](http://developer.yahooapis.com/TimeService/V1/getTime?appid=YahooDemo&output=json) which brings back the yahoo time...im guessing the PST

so i need to get this value with javascript...here is my code

```
$j.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://developer.yahooapis.com/TimeService/V1/getTime?appid=YahooDemo&output=json",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    complete: function(data){
      console.log(data);
      }
  });
```

but i cant seem to pull out that Timestamp out of the json...what am I doing wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to use the `success` callback:

```
$j.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://developer.yahooapis.com/TimeService/V1/getTime?appid=YahooDemo&output=json",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function(data,status,xhr){
      console.log(data.Result.Timestamp);
      }
  });​
```

Answer (score 5):

You're using the `complete` method, which returns the XHR object, not the result.
You want `success`:

```
$j.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://developer.yahooapis.com/TimeService/V1/getTime?appid=YahooDemo&output=json",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function(data){
      console.log(data.Response.Timestamp);
    }
});
```

Source: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 1):

The JSON looks like `{"Result":{"Timestamp":1331089290}}`.  That is, an object property called `Result`, which is another object literal containing the property `Timestamp`:

```
// Use .success rather than .complete
success: function(data){
    console.log(data.Result.Timestamp);
}
```

Comment: This is incorrect. `complete` callback receives the XHR object, not the data received by the response. `complete` callback **always** fires regardless if the XHR succeeds or not. Perhaps you meant to use `success`.

Answer (score 0):

javascript:

```
//change
dataType: "jsonp",
//to
dataType: "json",
```

Then extract the timestamp with `data.Result.Timestamp`.

When you use the value, remember that UNIX timestamp is in seconds whilst the javascript Date object works in milliseconds.